# Win 2019 DFS Replication not working across WAN / VPN, no errors

Tags: site-to-site-vpn, windows-server-2019, dfs, file-replication-services

I have a problem with DFS Replication. I've had replication at our main site working between two member servers for a while, but when I recently added a new site with a server, I ran into a lot of problems with disconnected topologies and syncing the configuration in AD. I finally got all that sorted, and both sites show that replication is active, have the correct targets, and verify topology successfully. All the connections are showing established.

However, none of the replication is happening between sites. The replication continues to operate normally at the main site. There are no recent DFSR errors in the Event Viewer on the servers involved in cross-site replication.

My current topology is that one of the servers at the primary site is functioning as a hub, and has two-way connections to each of the other servers (1 local, one over VPN). The VPN connection is a site-to-site link between two Sonicwall TZ600s.

Any guidance on what to check or look for? Without any errors or failure messages I'm at a loss for next steps.

Comment: Update: I've done some more digging and I've found that the files that should be replicating are showing an UpdateState of "Blocked" when running Get-DfsrState.

Answer (score 0):

Its always worth checking the staging volume sizes ( = to top 20 or so files, I believe 32 is the advice) and that GAV isn't dropping the stream on the SonicWalls, could be a fluffy cloud AV hit rather than definition based, effects things like AV repositories, etc.

DFSR also uses different ports depending on if the host is a DC or not, it may be worth looking for any dropped packets.

Comment: It's news to me that a DC uses "different" ports for DFS-R. Do you have a reference? Obviously a DC needs various ports for all the services it hosts, but DFS-R uses the same anywhere, unless it's been customised, is my understanding

Comment: My memory may have been around port 5722 but its been a while, ill dig up the last notes I found when creating my firewall service groups when I'm back in the office.  Noted the difference as we had 5722 in the DC service group.

Answer (score 0):

This is my mantra right now, but when you added the new host, did you pre-seed the data there before enabling replication?

If you haven't, you should.

And I concur with the comment about ensuring your staging size is sufficient as well, but the pre-seed is important.

If you've done the pre-seed *correctly* then an extract from the DFS-R diagnostic report showing a couple of the Blocked messages would be helpful. Add them to the main post.